# is it possible with highcharts 5 to plot a point at the top of the chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am wondering if it is possible to set the value of a series to always be the top of the current chart, more or less like using plotBands or plotLines.
For example, I would love to have a series like: [1,1], [1,yAxis.top] ...
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not know what is an axis max until you set it or let the Highcharts calculate it. I assume that you do not want to set [axis.max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max), so you need to wait until the Highcharts sets axis max and then add a max point dynamically. You can use a load event to achieve that.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {
            const axis = this.yAxis[0]
            const max = axis.max
            const series = this.series[0]

            axis.update({ max })
            series.addPoint(axis.max, true, false, false)
        }
    }
},
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/qb2tn7jh/